# AbstractMethodError from java.util.Hashtable while calling get method

Tags: java, hashtable

We have an Object `CollectedInfo`, which contains a `Hashtable`. In our application, we populate this `Hashtable`, and then iterate it to perform insert operations. Different threads used simultaneously to perform this operation.

While retrieving the value from the `Hashtable`, we see the `AbstractMethodError` exception, showing the trace from get method of `Hashtable`. As soon as this exception comes the java application crashes.

We are not able to reproduce the exception, however we can see the same behavior in our application very consistently over a period of time.

Below is the trace :

```
SYS_ERR: Exception running task: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
SYS_ERR: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
SYS_ERR:     at java.util.Hashtable.get(Unknown Source)
SYS_ERR:     at poll.CollectedInfo.getValuesForColumn(CollectedInfo.java:1026)
SYS_ERR:     at poll.YYYMgr.saveData(YYYMgr.java:5346)
SYS_ERR:     at poll.YYYMgr.saveData(YYYMgr.java:2412)
SYS_ERR:     at poll.YYYMgr.saveData(YYYMgr.java:2250)
SYS_ERR:     at poll.CommonPollAPI.saveData(CommonPollAPI.java:579)
SYS_ERR:     at poll.XXXXData.run(XXXXData.java:76)
SYS_ERR:     at management.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:70)
```

We are using the JRE 1.6.0, and the OS where this issue is reproduce is Linux Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.6 Beta (Tikanga).

Comment: You need to show some of your code

Comment: Are you seeing the same issue when running on other systems? Because what http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/AbstractMethodError.html is that this error comes due to calling of abstract method or  'definition of some class has incompatibly changed since the currently executing method was last compiled'

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd The class which load the information into the CollectedInfo Object is different, that class used to collect the data and add it in this Object, and then finally pass it to the YYMgr.saveData method. Here the iteration is done and the values are save in the DB. There are multiple instance of CollectedInfo Object invoked by individual thread, which collect the data and then save it to DB

Comment: @Ajj, the issue do not show up in normal load, but when we tried to save 20000 entries in collectedinfo (hashtable in it) it shows up after running for long time. If the issue is with related to different class, then it should comes everytime.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, a [`Hashtable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) is basically a [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), so...

You have:

- a `HashMap`
- Multiple threads using the `HashMap` concurrently

What *need* is a `HashMap` that is coded for concurrent access.

Fortunately, one exists already: [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html). The only change you'll need to you code is to use the special thread-safe method [`putIfAbsent(K, V)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent%28K,%20V%29)

Answer (score 1):

Take an Iterator class object and then try to get hash values.

//Declaration

```
 Iterator itr = hashtable.keySet().iterator();
```

// Processing

```
 while(itr.hasNext())
 { 
    String key = (String)itr.next();  
        String value = (String)hashtable.get(key); 

           // write your desired code
 }
```

Comment: What about competing threads? This doesn't protect against concurrent updates

Comment: Each thread, have it own object to dump the values. Hence there is no chance of getting into another lane. Right now I am testing this in Windows platform to check if there is anything to do with native lib